# Using Ember Data RestSerializer to POST to a 3rd-party API, how can I change the payload format?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am using Ember Data RestSerializer to POST to a 3rd-party API.

The JSON payload format that the API expects is:

`[{"key": "value"}]`

But all the normalization methods I find, like `serializeIntoHash`, seem to address the inner part of the payload:

```
{
  "modelName": [{"key": "value"}]
}
```

Is there a way to get rid of the root object and root key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're dealing with questions of [your store] -> [persistence layer], you usually are talking about the Adapter (not the Serializer).

I think [adapter#createRecord](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Adapter.html#method_createRecord) is what you want to override.

Comment: Thanks. This put me in the right track!
The code ended up looking like:
 DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  createRecord: function(store, type, record) {
    var data = this.serialize(record, { includeId: true });
    data = JSON.stringify(data); ...